# Stream Analytics CI/CD :The required property 'storageAccounts' is missing from the request."

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to do CI/CD for a Stream Analytics jobs.
In this i have 2 inputs :

- Datalake
- Reference data (where I am using SQL DW)

I have created the pipeline following the link https://github.com/SatyKrish/AzureStreamAnalytics-CICD

Once I have artifacts from pipeline ,i am trying to create Release.

I am getting Error "The required property 'storageAccounts' is missing from the request.".

When i see ARM template file i cann't see Storage Account and Storage Key inside properties for reference dataset.

I have configure Storage account in Visual studio but some how when Artifacts are generated ,it doesn't have Storage details for reference dataset

Answer (score 1):

Can you please make sure that you have the right version of the NuGet package :

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.StreamAnalytics.CICD/2.0.0

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Chirag For your help.

With updating the Nuget to 2.4.1 solved my both issues

(https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.StreamAnalytics.CICD)

Reference data
PowerBI